# How is Liquid monetized?

Tags: transaction-fees, liquid

I was reading about [how Liquid works](https://help.blockstream.com/hc/en-us/articles/900001408623-How-does-Liquid-Bitcoin-L-BTC-work-). Do Liquid transaction fees work the same way BTC fees do (per transaction)? Is there only Blockstream as a miner or are there other enterprises who collect the fees too?

Comment: Not an answer as i'm not 100% sure but from some bribes of conversations i got i think Blockstream collects the fees which helps them pay actual Bitcoin fees then

Comment: https://docs.blockstream.com/liquid/technical_overview.html#confidential-transactions mentions congestion; so how could there be congestion if it's a centralized chain? (Well, thanks anyway)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fees are collected to a "fee address". Blockstream uses this to fund the BTC fees incurred by "burning" the L-BTC needed to pay fees.

Fees are intended to be anti-spam rather than a revenue source. Monetization of Liquid is based on providing products and services on top of Liquid.